# Nodes are not able to Join the cluster

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I am new to EKS.
I am using a Jump server as my cluster is within a private VPC.
I am trying to create a node group for a cluster, and whatever I do I am getting the error: Nodes are not able to Join the cluster. I have added the node instance role to the config-map but still same issue.
When I check the cloudwatch log, I see the below error over and over again:
**> time="2023-12-11T06:58:55Z" level=warning msg="access denied" arn="arn:aws:iam::{My Account-Id}:role/GenLite-EKSNodeRole" client="127.0.0.1:57368" error="mapper EKSConfigMap renderTemplates error: error rendering username template "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}": failed querying private DNS from EC2 API for node i-06619817629a4d971: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::{Different Account Id}:assumed-role/eks-2fc8bbe1-e674-403e-93f1-776a-MasterInstanceRole-3Q7zGdghYXqr/i-0b653e95262d0be2f is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::{My Account-Id}:role/eksClusterRole\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: XXXX-XXX... " method=POST path=/authenticate**
GenLite-EKSNodeRole is my NodeInstance role and eksClusterRole is the role that allows access to other AWS service resources that are required to operate clusters managed by EKS.

1. "arn:aws:iam::{My Account-Id}:role/GenLite-EKSNodeRole is NodeInstance Role
2. I have no clue what is this-> User: arn:aws:sts::{Different Account Id}:assumed-role/eks-2fc8bbe1-e674-403e-93f1-776a-MasterInstanceRole-3Q7zGdghYXqr/i-0b653e95262d0be2f Neither do I recognize the account id associated with this ARN
3. i-06619817629a4d971 is the instance that the nodegroup creation is creating.

GenLite-EKSNodeRole

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Create a dedicated IAM role for EKS node management.",
    "Parameters": {
        "ProjectName":
        {
            "Default": "GenLite",
            "Description": "Cloud Project Name",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "NodeInstanceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RoleName": { "Fn::Sub": "${ProjectName}-EKSNodeRole" },
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/Client-SSM-EC2-POLICY"
                    },
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy"
                ],
                "Path": "/",
                "Policies": [
                    {
                        "PolicyName": "CNIMetricsHelperPolicy",
                        "PolicyDocument": {
                            "Version": "2012-10-17",
                            "Statement": [
                                {
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Action": "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                                    "Resource": "*"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "NodeInstanceRole": {
            "Description": "The node instance role",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "NodeInstanceRole",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

eksClusterRole

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Allows access to other AWS service resources that are required to operate clusters managed by EKS.",
    "Resources": {
        "EKSServiceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com",
                            "AWS": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/GenLite-EKSNodeRole"
                            ]
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Condition": {
                            "ArnLike": {
                                "aws:SourceArn": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:eks:*:AWS::${AWS::AccountId}:cluster/*"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "RoleName": "eksClusterRole",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "EKSServiceRoleArn": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "EKSServiceRole",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added all the roles I can think of to config-map.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<My account Id>:role/GenLite-EKSNodeRole
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<My account Id>:role/GenLite-EKSClusterAdmin
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:masters
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<My account Id>:role/AWSReservedSSO_SSO-MV-FullAccess-PermissionSet_a8b87ae27c393266
      username: cluster-admin
      groups:
        - system:masters
```

I have added GenLite-EKSNodeRole as a Principal to eksClusterRole. Thought may be that way the NodeInstance Role will be able to assume eksClusterRole. But to no avail.

Please help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong.